# Trouble importing sklearn.compose.make_column_selector in Jupyterlab

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-lab

I'm having some trouble importing the make_column_selector method from SciKit Learn. Here is my code and the resultant error:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.impute import MissingIndicator
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-c801fe55616f> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
----> 2 from sklearn.compose import make_column_selector
      3 from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
      4 from sklearn.impute import MissingIndicator
      5 from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

ImportError: cannot import name 'make_column_selector' from 'sklearn.compose' (C:\Users\azhad\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\__init__.py)
```

To confirm, I have updated anaconda with SciKitLearn version 0.23. Has anyone encountered this error? Please feedback if you know what's going on, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same error on scikitlearn version 0.21. After upgrading to the latest version (0.24.2) it worked fine.